# Mapping Data Flow Azure

Tags: azure-data-factory, linked-service, azure-mapping-data-flow

I am flattening a Json File to CSV file using mapping data flow in Azure data factory, the issue is that files is placed in storage container which is behind firewall. As it looks Only Auto Resolve integration runtime is supported in Mapping Data flow, while I cant create a linked service with AutoResolve integration runtime to connect  storage container, Am I missing something here, do we have a workaround for this.

Comment: One way would be to store the csv file to a storage account that has no firewall or uses only AutoResolve IR and then use copy data activity to copy from this storage to destination storage using your IR.

Comment: Yes, this is a workaround that I am following but I needed something that should work with firewalled storage container, but looks like it is the product design.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Dataflows do not support Self hosted IR's. The following image is the reference of the same:

[image]

- As a work around, you can store the csv file in a storage container which does not have private firewall settings. One this is done, you can copy this file to required private container using copy data with Self Hosted IR.
- Another alternative would be to use another service for transformations like Databricks notebook to complete the operation directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the managed vnet option in the Azure IR which will allow you to connect to the storage account using data flows by creating a private link from ADF to your storage.